# Frames not working in HTML5

Tags: html, frames

I have a task to do and I know that I should not be using frames but I have to. I tried to load 3 html pages into 3 frames on the main page but it's showing absolutely nothing at all. This is the code:

```
<body>
<h4>BGJUG - Bulgarian Java User Group</h4>
<div class="menu">
    ABOUT EVENTS CONTACTS SEARCH
    <hr width="90%" />
</div>
<frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">
    <frame src="a.html">
    <frame src="b.html">
    <frame src="c.html">
</frameset>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using HTML5? As per this documentation (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp), the frameset tag has been discontinued.
,

Comment: While `frameset` are entirely obsolete in html5, a frameset needs to be a direct child of `html`  and is used instead of `body` you might want to use `iframe` instead.

Comment: Just in case also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259232/alternative-for-frames-in-html5-using-iframes

Comment: thanks, the solution was to put the frameset direct under the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `<frameset>` tag is not supported in HTML5.  You will need to change your DOCTYPE to one that supports frames.  Try this:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">`

Also, see the comment by t.niese about framesets being direct children of `<html>`.

Alternatively, if you need the HTML5 features, you can accomplish the same thing with `<iframe>`. <strike>inside CSS boxes.  Scrolling of `<iframe>` is also not supported in HTML5 but you can probably put the `<iframe>` tags in CSS boxes with `overflow: scroll;`.</strike>  See the *other* comment by t.niese below this answer.

Comment: `[...] Scrolling of <iframe> is also not supported in HTML5 [...]` can you give a reference to this? IMHO only the `scrolling` attribute is not supported anymore, so if you would like to **disable**  the scrolling on the iframe you would need to use `overflow: hidden` on the `iframe`

Comment: @t.niese:  I found that here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp  I realize that's not the most authoritative source in the world, but I'd have expected that one to be corrected quickly if it were wrong.

Comment: _w3schools_ still has many inaccuracies that are misleading (like in this case), but they also just say that the  `scrolling` attribute is not supported anymore. But you will have to apply `overflow: auto|scroll|visible` to the `iframe` itself and not on a surrounding element, and the use of scrollbars is the default  for `iframe`s.