# What may I be missing for showing search result in a table on a second frame in a JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, frames

I have a JSP page that after searching, and getting a result from backend, should display a table in a frame below the first frame, containing search fields and buttons etc. I get all results from backend (shown in sysout) but I am missing something because my table is not displayed. In fact I believe the whole second frame is not shown.

First JSP containing both frames:

```
</head>
<frameset border="0" cols="100%" rows="100%">
<frame name="eoSupersessionHeader" src="/glopps/processEoSupersession.do?method=initializeForm" noresize="noresize">
<frame name="eoSupersessionResult" src="/glopps/jsp/extendedOffer/eoSupersessionTable.jsp" noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
<NOFRAMES><BODY><P>To view this page, you need a browser that supports frames.</P></BODY></NOFRAMES>
<noframes>
```

When debugging using F12 I find that my second frame, the one containing my table, isn't loaded/doesn't containg any HTML code at all, whilst the first one contains its HTML.
[image: Debugging result]

Any sggestions as to what I might have missed or what I might need to add?

Comment: eek - frames - run - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18259464/2310289

Comment: Yes, I know frames aren't the most convenient way. However, the system I'm coding in are using it and I want to follow the standard used today for other parts of the system. The system is obviously not brand new...